# R data.frame to JSON where each data point has column name and value

Tags: r, json

Hard to describe exactly in one title but what I'm trying to use an API and need data in a very specific Json format.

The data I'm using is simple:

```
     debtinc loan mortdue  value
6   37.11361 1700   30548  40320
8   36.88489 1800   28502  43034
20  31.58850 2300  102370 120953
26  38.26360 2400   34863  47471

#data sample:
df <- structure(list(debtinc = c(37.113613558, 36.884894093, 31.588503178, 
    38.263600731, 29.681827045, 30.051136286), loan = c(1700L, 1800L, 
    2300L, 2400L, 2400L, 2900L), mortdue = c(30548, 28502, 102370, 
    34863, 98449, 103949), value = c(40320, 43034, 120953, 47471, 
    117195, 112505)), row.names = c(6L, 8L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 35L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I am trying to transform in this json format. where each row is a single json object in a specific format:

```
# col1_row1 = numeric
# col1_row2 = char
 
{"inputs": [
               {"name": "<col1_name>", "value": <col1_row1>}, \
               {"name": "<col2_name>", "value": "<col2_row1>"}, \
               {"name": "<col3_name>"} \ # if Value: NA
               ]
}
```

my real struggle is transforming each column to a "name": "column1" and "value": "col1_val1"

My closes trial:

```
library("jsonlite")

df_list<- unname(split(test, 1:nrow(test)))

lapply(df_list, function(x) toJSON(list(inputs = x)))
```

Which gets me this, which is in object type I need, but not in the correct json format columns are key rather than value:

```
[1] "{\"inputs\":[{\"debtinc\":37.1136,\"loan\":1700,\"mortdue\":30548,\"value\":40320}]}"  
[2] "{\"inputs\":[{\"debtinc\":36.8849,\"loan\":1800,\"mortdue\":28502,\"value\":43034}]}"  
[3] "{\"inputs\":[{\"debtinc\":31.5885,\"loan\":2300,\"mortdue\":102370,\"value\":120953}]}"
[4] "{\"inputs\":[{\"debtinc\":38.2636,\"loan\":2400,\"mortdue\":34863,\"value\":47471}]}"  
[5] "{\"inputs\":[{\"debtinc\":29.6818,\"loan\":2400,\"mortdue\":98449,\"value\":117195}]}" 
[6] "{\"inputs\":[{\"debtinc\":30.0511,\"loan\":2900,\"mortdue\":103949,\"value\":112505}]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit]
After a year, I've stumbled on this again, and I've overhauled, more reliable and faster than before. If the Value is `NA` it will return only "name", this work as intended for the api the output payload is aimed to.

```r
write_json_row <- function(row) {

    var_vect <- paste0('{"name": "', colnames(row), '"', 
                      ifelse(sapply(row, is.na), '', 
                      ifelse(sapply(row, is.character), paste0(', "value": ', '"', row, '"'), 
                      ## the "error" string output may give a silent error
                      ## it is here for placeholder because if I add stop() it
                      ## will halt the function, even though it is never returning "error"
                      ifelse(sapply(row, is.numeric), paste0(', "value": ', row), "error"))), ' } ')
    
    out <- paste0('{"inputs": [ ', paste0(var_vect, collapse = ", "), '] }')
    
    return(out)
    
    
}

## apply the function to each row of a DF

out <- by(df, seq_len(nrow(df)), write_json_row)
out
```

---

[Before Edit]
As an addition to the previous answer, it didn't cover the case when you had character and numeric variables, `pivot_longer` would fail (my mistake with the data sample).

To fix, I would transform everything to character and then strip the quotes where there is number before or after. This is a poor regex, but there is a way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- sapply(df, as.character)
df <- as.data.frame(df) 

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%  
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%   
  split(x = .[-1], f = .$id) %>%  
  unname %>% 
  lapply(function(x) toJSON(list(inputs = x))) %>%
  unlist %>%
  gsub(r'{"(?=\d)|(?<=\d)"}', "", ., perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivoting to long format makes this work. Convieniently `pivot_longer` defaults to "name" and "value" as column names:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  split(x = .[-1], f = .$id) %>%
  unname %>%
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = T)
# [
#   [
#     {
#       "name": "debtinc",
#       "value": 37.1136
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "loan",
#       "value": 1700
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "mortdue",
#       "value": 30548
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "value",
#       "value": 40320
#     }
#   ],
#   [
#     {
#       "name": "debtinc",
#       "value": 36.8849
#     },
#  ...
```

It's at least a lot closer - from your example I'm having trouble telling exactly where the nesting and `"inputs:"` need to go.

Comment: There is no "nesting" for "inputs", it's just a format the API requests, even though it is for a single row. But that is much easy to add. I'll try some in your snippet.
I was avoiding using dplyr/plyr, but if this is the way to go :)
Thanks

Comment: With your trick, this should do the work easily:
`df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  split(x = .[-1], f = .$id) %>%
  unname %>%
lapply(function(x) toJSON(list(inputs = x)))`

Comment: I will wait to see if someone shows with a base or simpler solution, otherwise will mark as resolved :)